# Advanced mongoDB query in Matlab using mongo-java-driver

Tags: java, matlab, mongodb

I'm trying to perform a mongoDB query from matlab using mongo-java-driver-2.13.1.jar. I'm not familiar to mongodb, but I've a query which works fine with robomongo. The query is:

```
db.getCollection('ForecastPrice').find({'forecast': ObjectId('553e24c1a46da1d1498b4567')})
```

In matlab I'm able to connect to the remote database, browse and retrieve collections. These are the steps I follow to connect from Matlab:

```
clear; clc

javaaddpath('/home/maurice/MATLAB/myJavaClasses/mongo-java-driver-2.13.1.jar')

import com.mongodb.*

% Connect to remote server
m = Mongo('5.xxx.105.xxx',27017); % 

% open DB
db = m.getDB('database');

% Authentication
db.authenticate('User','WCaAjaks');

% See collection:
colls = db.getCollectionNames(); % get collection name
% Read a collection:
clients = db.getCollection('Clients')

% Read data from a collection
fcstPrices = db.getCollection('ForecastPrice').find(); % OK!!!
```

But if I try to filter by ObjectId's i receive the following error:

```
>> fcstPrices = db.getCollection('ForecastPrice').find({'forecast': ObjectId('553e24c1a46da1d1498b4567')})
Undefined function 'ObjectId' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

I could loop along the values of this collection comparing the ID's and keeping those from my interest, but this is not elegant neither fast when accessing big collections:

```
size_fcstRes = fcstPrices.size;
nombre_fcstRes = fcstPrices.count %% Es el mateix que size?

output = {};
for i=1:size_fcstRes

    if i==1
        valors = char(fcstPrices.one);
    else
        valors = char(fcstPrices.next);
    end

    strc_valors = loadjson(valors);

    try

    if strcmp(id_prod, strc_valors.content.products.id)                    % Check if it is the ID we are looking for

        if strcmp(nomVar, strc_valors.content.products.variables.name)     % Check if it is the Variable we are looking for

            display(num2str(i))

            start_date = datenum((strc_valors.content.date), 'yyyymmddHHMMSS' );                         % Data del primer valor
            values = strc_valors.content.products.variables.values;        % Valors

            output{i,1} = cat(2, start_date, values);

        end

    end

    catch error_mongodb

        display(['Error: ', error_mongodb.message])

    end
end
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this. I have to get some data from mongoDB and I would like to do it from Matlab, since my scripts are totally written with Matlab.

Thanks.

Comment: about error, have you tried without ObjectId , just string?

Comment: I've tried many combinations but none of them works. The output is always the same: "No method 'find' with matching signature found for class 'com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ForecastEntries_Coll = db.getCollection('ForecastEntries');

ID = '553e24c1a46da1d1498b4567';

query = BasicDBObject('forecast', ObjectId(ID));

fcstResources = ForecastEntries_Coll.find(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra import as [`ObjectId` belongs to `org.bson.types`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html).

---

Straight from [the Matab documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html#f46341), something along the lines of that should do the trick to import `ObjectId`:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
```

Comment: Thanks for you comments Sylvain. How can I import this class/package to Matlab?

Comment: @jordividal [Glad to have helped you.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) I'm not a Matlab specialist, but from what I read [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html#f46341), you only need an extra import statement. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I tried importing ' org.bson.types.ObjectId' as suggested by [sylvain-leroux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363712/sylvain-leroux), but it didn't work. I think there's not an easy solution, since mongo-java-driver is looking for " in the lines while Matlab doesn't allow them:

```
fcstResources = db.getCollection('ForecastEntries').find({"forecast": ObjectId("553e24c1a46da1d1498b4567")}); % KO
                                                           |
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

This 'input character' refers to the ". On the other hand, if I try with Matlab sintaxis it doesn't work either:

```
fcstResources = db.getCollection('ForecastEntries').find({'forecast': ObjectId('553e24c1a46da1d1498b4567')}); % KO
Undefined function 'colon' for input arguments of type 'org.bson.types.ObjectId'.
```

Looks like I'm in a dead end.... it is probably not posible to make such kind of mongodb queries from Matlab :-(